# Нормальный вывод ошибок с proc macro attribute [Rust]

Tags: rust

Я делал свои собственные макросы-атрибуты, и заметил проблему.

При добавлении макроса

```
#[GET("/")]
fn index() {
    load!("../static/index.html")
}
```

С появлением ошибки, она скрывается за макросом, без точного вывода строки и места с ошибкой

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src\main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | #[GET("/")]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^
  | |
  | expected `u8`, found `&str`
  | expected due to this
  |
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `GET` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Какими средствами можно это исправить?

Comment: Игра такая есть, rust называется

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer спасибо, играл когда-то.....

Comment: Я не гик по данному языку, но вам же написано `запустите с параметром -Z для получения дополнительной информации.`

Comment: @Kotomi я пытался, но единственное что оно показывает, то это имя и нахождение файла в котором был объявлен макрос ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: Diagnostic API с нормальными спанами все еще не стабилизирован, но слышал, что можно в сторону https://lib.rs/proc-macro-error пробовать смотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял что не так.

В реализации макроса, я несколько раз конвертировал ввод между типами String/TokenStream. От этого вывод считался компилятором ошибкой в РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ макроса, а не в его вводе.

Во избежание этого, нужные части `Block` храните в исходном виде. А нужные реализации можно модифицировать через парсинг в структуры с `syn`.
Но при этом даже после парсинга в структуру из `syn`, и последующим конвертацией через `quote!`, трейсинг ошибок остается, и ошибки в блок-кодах выводиться правильно.

Поэтому стоит частично отказаться от злоупотреблением `Regex`, в пользу ручной конфигурации.